# How do interactive CLIs work?

Tags: vim, tty, console, ncurses

How do command-line applications like Vim work? Specifically, how do they take control of the terminal in the manner they do? Also, for future reference, is there a specific term for applications that take control of the terminal the way Vim does?

Comment: A term I've seen used for such programs is `full-screen terminal applications`.  The word `terminal` tries to indicate it's a text display rather than GUI, and `full-screen` indicates the program moves the terminal's cursor around the screen rather than merely writing one line at a time (and depending on the terminal to scroll the accumulated lines).

Comment: In my mind, you're asking about an interactive opposite-of-a-CLI!  A hallmark of a CLI is that you type a command line, and when you're happy with it, you hit RETURN.  But I think what you're asking about is programs that process each key immediately as you hit it.  They do that (under Unix/Linux, anyway) by putting the terminal driver into "raw" or "cbreak" mode.

Comment: I've seen "TUI" used for such [text-based user interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) (to distinguish it from a pixel-based GUI).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

vim and other semi-graphical (the capability to display semi-graphic characters such as corners, full crosses…) applications control the terminal (manage the position of the cursor, the position of displayable characters, color settings…) by sending dedicated escape sequences, control codes that the terminal will translate into some dedicated action it will execute.

Because it would be just a nightmare for any programmer to echo the escape sequences to the stdout, not to say implying non portable code since there have always been many different terminals with different capabilities and different escape sequences,

a library abstracting all that work was created : *curses*. Nowadays named [ncurses](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses) which also provides higher level functions such as window management.

ncurses relies on the [terminfo](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html) database for acquiring the appropriate terminal description of capabilities.

It is thanks to this library of functions that *vim, iptraf-ng, alsa amixer, less, gdb,* the primary kernel configuration utility and many other control the terminal.

---

Note that these apps are typically not called "*command-line*" utilities which generally handle a single line of input with basic cursor management and editing facilities thanks to the [readline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) library.
Per contrast and as you can read in the `ncurses` man page linked hereabove, these programs can be called : *Interactive, Screen Oriented.* `vim` is typically named a *screen-oriented* editor per contrast to `ed` the *line-oriented* editor.

---

Note following suggestion in comments :

When started, the application will inherit the tty driver settings from the shell that launched it which are likely to be very similar to those initially set by the original agetty.
This including buffering of input until catching a newline charater, echoing of input keys at instant cursor's position… all sort of features whatever screen oriented application is not likely to want

When initializing, the program will save current tty driver settings and force those according to the programmer wishes.
Before quitting… the programmer is strongly invited to restore the initial settings… unless facing the risk of coming back to the calling shell in rather unpredictable but certainly messy conditions…

Comment: Another piece of the puzzle is how the application turns off the tty driver's pre-processing (of keystroke input from the terminal) and post-processing (of display output to the terminal).  And, of course, remembers the original tty driver settings in order to restore them when the application quits.

Comment: @SottoVoce : Do you mean what def/reset_prog_mode() achieve behind the scene ?

Comment: Or at the shell level, `stty raw`, `stty cooked`, and similar operations

Comment: @MC68020 I'm not familiar with the routine you mentioned.  I was thinking of the calls to do the equivalents of the `stty` commands as @roaima said, though I think for a C/C++ program like `vim` they're `ioctl()` calls to get and set the tty line disiplines.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I think the name of the interactive terminal applications that the OP and others here are looking for is in the tags for the question:
`console application` - Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

One character at a time goes into a buffer.
When the carriage return is entered, the buffer is examined ("parsed") one character at a time looking for tokens arranged in a given syntax.
Then, if possible, some command is executed accordingly. If the input can't be parsed, then an error message is given showing what the command interpreter couldn't figure out how to handle.

Rinse and repeat, until the command line interpreter is halted and/or the computer is shut down.

Basically, it's like any other computer program. Inputs, IF and ELSE statements, data manipulation (doing calculations and moving data around in memory), and outputs.